# Appending to a column with conditions

Tags: r

For the given data frame:

```
id |conv   
 1 | 0 |  
 1 | 0 |   
 1 | 0 |   
 1 | 1 |   
 1 | 0 |  
 1 | 1 |  
 1 | 0 |  
 1 | 0 |  
 2 | 0 |  
 2 | 1 |  
 2 | 0 |  
 2 | 1 |  
 2 | 1 |
```

conv has just two values 0 or 1. Basically when conv =1 and the id is same then '_1' should be appended for the subsequent ids . Then for the same id if we get another conv = 1 , '_2' should be appended to the id.I need to append in the id every time conv = 1 and id does not change.  My output should be :

```
id |conv   
 1 | 0 |  
 1 | 0 |   
 1 | 0 |   
 1 | 1 |   
 1_1 | 0 |  
 1_1 | 1 |  
 1_2 | 0 |  
 1_2 | 0 |  
 2 | 0 |  
 2 | 1 |  
 2_1 | 0 |  
 2_1 | 1 |  
 2_2 | 0 |  
 2_2 | 0 |
```

since the data is huge i cannot use for loop.

Comment: Why the 'conv' values in the input and output change esp the last 4 values?

Comment: @Sotos I didn't see your post while answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `ave` from `base R`

```
i1 <- with(df1, ave(conv==1, id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(dplyr::lag(x, default = FALSE))))
with(df1, ifelse(i1==0, id, paste(id, i1, sep="_")))
```

Answer (score 4):

One idea would be to first create an indicator variable which is the cumsum of `conv` per `id`. We subtract 1 when `conv == 1` and simply paste the non-zero one to id

```
ind <- with(df, ave(conv, id, FUN = cumsum))
ind[df$conv == 1] <- ind[df$conv == 1] - 1
df$id <- ifelse(ind == 0 , df$id, paste0(df$id, '_', ind))
df
#    id conv
#1    1    0
#2    1    0
#3    1    0
#4    1    1
#5  1_1    0
#6  1_1    1
#7  1_2    0
#8  1_2    0
#9    2    0
#10   2    1
#11 2_1    0
#12 2_1    1
#13 2_2    1
```